way in adnroid to start a background process or thread, which would run without stopping
Is there a way in adnroid to start a background process or thread,
which would run without stopping after closing the application?
In this process I want to place a receiver for messages from other users of the application (chat client).
During the downtime period, incoming messages will not be received.
Whats App, for example, is always ready to receive messages.
I tried Service and WorkManager. They've been working for a while
time after closing the application, but then stop.

"Whats App, for example, is always ready to receive messages" -- why do you think that WhatsApp is using the technique that you are describing? They might be using Firebase Cloud Messaging, for example. "Is there a way in adnroid to start a background process or thread, which would run without stopping after closing the application?" -- no.

I don't know how WhatsApp works. I doubt WhatsApp uses FCM, because he appeared earlier

I do not know what "he appeared earlier" means, sorry.

Sorry for my English. WhatsApp release date is February 2009.
Firebase launch date is April 2012, and acquired by Google in 2014.

"WhatsApp release date is February 2009" -- that is 15 years ago, before a lot of the restrictions on background processing were put in place. "Firebase launch date is April 2012, and acquired by Google in 2014." -- Firebase is a brand name. Firebase Cloud Messaging originated as Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) in 2010. While WhatsApp would not have needed C2DM/FCM at the outset, it certainly will need it now on Google Play ecosystem devices.

You can use FCM
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging
This is probably the simplest method because firebase already supports everything you need.
